# Key pair custom pass - Keystore

Tags: keystore

I'd like to store a few pair values  in my **Keystore**, so, asking by alias (user) try to recover pass. But generating them using **Keytool**, I can't create a KeyPair with a custom private key (pass). Is it possible?

Thanks.